# Symfony 5 doctrine flush slows down

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine, flush

I was just wondering why updating a record (flush) slows down over time.
For example, if i want to check mulitple records and compare them with eachother and after comparisation update a column like setCompared(true);. The first 1000 records are fine and fast but after that, the flush seems like it slows down after each flush. Is there a reason for that, like maybe it builds up or something. Do i need to clear() after flush().

Does anyone have a explaination for that?

Comment: Do you flush inside the loop after each comparison? The best strategy to flush is to wait for a few iterations (using a variable to count) and flush when it reaches a certain limit (say 20 or 30 for example). In between flushes you can clear the em.

Comment: Thank you, so flush in batches? Will that increase the update speed or at the minimum remains the same speed as the first 1000 rows?

Comment: You should use the profiler and test it out to see if this fixes your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like this according to the [Doctrine documentation)](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/batch-processing.html#bulk-inserts) :

```
<?php

$batchSize = 20;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10000; ++$i) {
    $user = new CmsUser;
    $user->setStatus('user');
    $user->setUsername('user' . $i);
    $user->setName('Mr.Smith-' . $i);
    $em->persist($user);
    if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
        $em->flush();
        $em->clear(); // Detaches all objects from Doctrine!
    }
}
$em->flush(); // Persist objects that did not make up an entire batch
$em->clear();
```

The following code shows an example for inserting 10000 objects with a batch size of 20. This means that we insert them 20 by 20 with the `flush()`.

Comment: Yes i saw that to. I wonder if this will prefend the slowing down overtime. I have implemented the solution and as the documentation suggested also dissabled the logger (->setSQLLogger(null);). Hope this helps :D